# Unique script tags not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jscript, asp.net-mvc-partialview, cascadingdropdown

I am creating a list of partial views on my main view. The partial view uses cascade dropdown lists. The cascade dropdowns work well on the first row however when I add a second row and change the value on the first dropdown the 2 second ones also get change instead of he one in the row I am just updating. 
I researched and know that it is because of my script is using the same tag for both of them and not being unique.
I started using `Html.BeginCollectionItem()` to get unique names on my dropdowns and modified my script to get the value of the hidden field and tie to the right dropdown but it is not working.

Any ideas how can I have unique ids in my script?

This is my partial view:

```
@model BudgetPortalMVC4.Models.NewBudgetModel
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem(""))
{
    <script type="text/jscript">
        $(function () {
            var value = document.getElementsByName(".index")[0].value;
            $(document).on('change', "#["+value+"].SelectedCategory", function () {
                $("#["+value+"].SelectedSubCategory").empty();
                $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetSubCategories")', { id: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
                    if (!data) {
                        return;
                    }
                    $("#["+value+"].SelectedSubCategory").append($('<option></option>').val('0').text('Select Item'));
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        $("#["+value+"].SelectedSubCategory").append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
                    })
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <table>
       <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedCategory)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCategory, Model.CategoriesList, "Please select", new { @class = "SelectedCategory" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedCategory)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedSubCategory)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSubCategory,    Model.SubCategoriesList, "Please select", new { @class = "SelectedSubCategory" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedSubCategory)
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

This is part of the code it generates when rendered:

```
<input type="hidden" name=".index" autocomplete="off" value="b6fadec7-eb7d-4ce2-a06c-79ef0597b8da" />

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <label for="">SelectedCategory</label>
                <select class="SelectedCategory" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SelectedCategory must be a number." name=[b6fadec7-eb7d-4ce2-a06c-79ef0597b8da].SelectedCategory"><option value="">Please select</option>
                    <option value="1">Groceries</option>
                    <option value="2">Travel</option>
                </select>
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="[b6fadec7-eb7d-4ce2-a06c-79ef0597b8da].SelectedCategory" data-valmsg replace="true"></span>
```

An this is the error my script is throwing when trying to make the tag unique:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[4eebf546-988d-44a0-aa4e-296c46273d54].SelectedCategory
>   throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );

Comment: First, remove you script from the partial and put it in the main view (scripts should never be in partials). Then give you elements class names so that you select then by class name, not ID.

Comment: And if you look at the html your generating, you will see that there are no elements with `id="[####].SelectedCategory"` - they would be `id="_####__SelectedCategory"` (except in your case there will be no `id` attributes on the form controls because you model is a collection rather than an object contain a property which is a collection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scripts should never be in partials. Move the script to the main view (or layout) and use your elements class names in `jQuery` selectors.

You partial should be

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem(""))
{
    <div class="item">
        <label>
            <span>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.SelectedCategory)</span>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCategory, Model.CategoriesList, "Please select", new { @class = "SelectedCategory" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedCategory)
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.SelectedSubCategory)</span>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSubCategory, Model.SubCategoriesList, "Please select", new { @class = "SelectedSubCategory" })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedSubCategory)
        </label>
    </div>
}
```

Note that because your model is `IEnumerable<T>`, the `HtmlHelper` methods will not generate an `id` attribute oro your form controls, so if you want labels, they need to wrap the control.

Note also that even if `id` attributes were created (assumingyour model was an object containing a property for the collection), the `HtmlHelper` methods replace any `[`, `]` and `.` characters with and underscore to prevent a conflict with `jQuery` selectors, so something like `#[4eebf546-988d-44a0-aa4e-296c46273d54].SelectedCategory` would never exist in the view.

Then change the script to

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetSubCategories", "Budget")'; // Do not hard code your url's
$(document).on('change', '.SelectedCategory', function() {
    var subCategory = $(this).closest('.item').find('.SelectedSubCategory');
    subCategory.empty();
    $.getJSON(url, { id: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
        if (!data) {
            return;
        }
        subCategory.append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select')); // Do not give the option a value!
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            subCategory.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
        });
    });
});
```

Note you also replace `$(document)` with the closest ancestor that exists in the document when the page is first rendered (e.g. that might be `$('form')`)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I made the changes the code is working, I am getting this response [{"Value":1,"Text":"Vegetables"},{"Value":2,"Text":"Ice Cream"},{"Value":3,"Text":"Meat"}]. However it is not being updated in the second dropdown. Any ideas?

Comment: Then you have not followed my answer. Debug your script and check the values - for example what does `console.log(subCategory.length);` return? Also I noticed your code was missing a `>` in `subCategory.append($('<option</option>').val(...` and I have updated the answer (I assume that was a typo on your part, but if not, that would have caused the script to fail)

Comment: This is what I get: ReferenceError: subCategory is not defined. I tried to change $(document) for $('form') but it didn't work. Maybe I just need some documentation.

Comment: Did you add the `<div class="item">` element to the partial view? If you do not use the code I gave you, then you cannot expect it to work :)

Comment: And note also that your not going to get any client side validation for the new items. Suggest you read the links I gave you in your previous question again - you need to re-parse the validator.

Comment: Silly me, i forgot to add  the class="item". I did that and it is working fine. I think now i can start working in the submit button part. Thank you for the help.